# Insert multiple lists into table using sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to insert two lists into the table where one list is inserted into one column and the other into another column where item 1 from list 1 is held in the same record as item 1 in list 2. The length of both lists is 73.

airfields = ['Andrewsfield','Bagby','Beccles'...]
icao_codes = ['EGSL','EGNG','EGSM'...]

| AirfieldID | Name | ICAO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Andrewsfield | EGSL |
| 2 | Bagby | EGNG |
| 3 | Beccles | EGSM |

This is my code, but I get an error message when I run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 33, in <module>
    data_entry()
  File "main.py", line 30, in data_entry
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO Airfields (Name, ICAO) VALUES (?, ?)""", (airfields[count],), (icao_codes[count],))
TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

```
def data_entry():
   count = 1
   while count != 73
      c.execute("""INSERT INTO Airfields (Name, ICAO) VALUES (?, ?)""", (airfields[count],), (icao_code[count],))
      count = count + 1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Python provides more error-related information .

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 33, in <module>
    data_entry()
  File "main.py", line 30, in data_entry
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO Airfields (Name, ICAO) VALUES (?, ?)""", (airfields[count],), (icao_codes[count],))
TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Comment: In the question, not as comment.

Comment: Is that what you meant? Sorry I'm new to stack overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO Airfields (Name, ICAO) VALUES (?, ?)""", (airfields[count],), (icao_codes[count],))
TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

[`execute`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) takes its values as a [tuple](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp). You've passed two tuples, `(airfields[count],)` and  `(icao_codes[count],)`. With the SQL statement that means 3 arguments, `execute` takes 2.

You'd use one tuple, a single set of parenthesis, for all values: `(airfields[count], icao_codes[count])`.

```
c.execute("""INSERT INTO Airfields (Name, ICAO) VALUES (?, ?)""", (airfields[count], icao_codes[count]))
```

---

Note: You can write your loop better with [`for x in range`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp).

```
 for count in range(1, 72):
   c.execute("""INSERT INTO Airfields (Name, ICAO) VALUES (?, ?)""", (airfields[count], icao_code[count]))
```